# High current ferrite beads

Tags: dc-dc-converter, emc, ferrite-bead

I've found ferrite beads work great for eliminating high frequency noise on the input and output of DC-DC converters, but now I have a DC-DC converter that is outputting 20A and ferrite beads work at a maximum of 10A (and not great that high). What are my options?

The switching frequency of the converter is 350kHz and the high frequency noise I'm trying to get rid of it above 100MHz, differential noise. I need a board-mount solution that is not huge and ideally not custom-wound. Should or could I put a bunch of 10A beads in parallel?

Comment: You didn't say how high frequency you're interested in.  But have you looked at MPP cores?

Comment: We need more information there are beads that will run at 20A or more but they will be big and expensive. What's your main operating frequency, the frequency of your noise and is it differential or common mode? If you can supply a picture from your scope that will help too,

Comment: Two (or three) parallel beads? Heatsink?

Comment: The switching frequency of the converter is 350kHz and the high frequency noise I'm trying to get rid of it above 100MHz, differential noise. I need a board-mount solution that is not huge and ideally not custom-wound. Should I/could I put a bunch of 10A beads in parallel?

Comment: I've added the detail you supplied to the question where it belongs. Please don't use comments for this.

Comment: Show the drawings of your PCB. Lets figure out why you have lots of 100MHz "noise".

Comment: Layout can be critical as suggested by @analogsystemsrf PCB drawings would help together with a circuit diagram.